# how to avoid audio initial 0.5s latency on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, audio

On a Mac laptop (OS 10.9.5), when playing sounds from a python program I will get an initial start-up latency of 0.5 s before the sound plays. If I have been playing sound within the last minute or so, there is no such latency. I have seen passing references to this kind of thing online but without much insight (e.g., http://music.columbia.edu/pipermail/portaudio/2014-November/016364.html). I looked for an Apple API way to disable it (like there is for the screen saver) but did not see anything obvious. The issue might be specific to laptops, as a power-saving feature for example. It happens not only on battery power, but also when plugged in.

Question: From python on OSX, how to tell the Mac to do whatever it needs to do to avoid that 0.5 sec latency the first time it plays a sound?

Constraints: Calling some command like `pmset` via subprocess is acceptable, unless it needs root (sudo) priv's; i.e., only normal user-space commands are acceptable. Also not acceptable: its easy to write a little thread to play a short ~silent sound every 30sec or so, but that will add some complexity to the program and use resources -- there has to be a better way to do it.

Comment: It would be useful if you could include a minimal example so that someone could try to repro your problem.

Comment: Good idea, @jaket, minimal examples are great. I mocked one up using pyaudio and did not get the 0.5s latency, which is very interesting. Its hard to provide a minimal example of my case, which is playing sound in a desktop app called PsychoPy, which uses pyo for sound. I also see the latency when using pysoundcard / pysoundfile instead of pyo, also 0.5s. I was hoping it was something that could be fixed with a mac system setting, but that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Is the delay possibly due to attempting to play a HUGE sound file ? Is the media file previously loaded into memory prior to this request to render it ?

Try to load the audio media into a buffer then upon a play signal perform the render directly from the buffer

Comment: Nice idea but that is definitely not the issue. Yes, the media file is pre-loaded into memory, or is generated data already in memory, and this makes no difference. And its only the first time you play a sound that it happens, not subsequently (if there has been a recent sound). And its small sounds, 1 second long, nothing huge.

Comment: possibly python is doing a lazy load of the audio libraries until they're called ... though unless the system is thrashing/swapping out due to low available RAM once audio is rendered seems very strange to get subsequent delays beyond initial rendering ... you could tease apart this question by seeing if same symptions occur on a machine with tons of free RAM

Comment: Don't think so... If I play a sound, then have that python process wait for 60 second, and play a second sound, there is a 0.5s latency for the second sound to start. But if the intervening interval is 30 seconds, there's no such latency. Presumably python is not unloading the audio libs in the former case (60 sec) but not the latter (30 sec).

Comment: yep, ~4G RAM available, same behavior.

Comment: If its feasible, craft from scratch the minimal code necessary to simply load file then render audio ... possibly there are some artifacts outside these steps which is impinging ... stranger things have happened ... then post this minimum code online so we can take a closer look if executing the minimal code continues to give this time lag